# Выбрать первый элемент на печатной странице

Tags: css, css3, print

Можно ли как-то при помощи css-селектора указать на первый элемент каждой печатной страницы?

Нечто по аналогии с `:first-child`, `:first-line`, `:first-letter`.

Answer (score 1):

Что-то вроде:

```
@media print {
  *:first-child{
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Ну-ка, в адресную строку хрома `data:text/html,<!doctype html><title>Test</title><style>@media print { *:first-child { color: red; } } p { page-break-after: always; }</style><p>123<p>456<script>print()</script>` и посмотреть на цвет абзаца на второй странице. first-child - это вложенность в структуре dom, а страница не совсем в ней. К тому же звёздочка лишняя.